# What are the Pancha Lakshmana (Five Characteristics) of Puranas?

Tags: puranas, reference-request

Puranas have five characteristics. That means these texts describe mainly five topics. These are something like creation, dissolution, genealogy. This is what I vaguely know. What are these five characteristics? Please explain in detail. And most importantly what is the source? Where can I find the reference to these five characteristics that define Purana?

Comment: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/essay/matsya-purana-critical-study/d/doc628398.html.         Hope the above reference  gives a satisfactory explanation

Comment: @Athrey I saw a verse there. What is the verse number?

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay Shiva Purana 7.1.1.40b-7.1.1.41a, Skanda Purana 5.3.1.31; 7.1.2.84, etc.